# Java loses UI settings after changing system font anti-aliasing

Tags: java, swing, fonts, antialiasing

When running below simple app and changing font anti-aliasing (WIN+R "sysdm.cpl" -> System Properties -> Advanced -> Performance Settings -> Smooth edges of screen fonts) one can see that the JTextArea gets the wrong font (and stays with it also if toggle anti-aliasing again):

[image: On the left side initially correct, then on the right the font is wrong.]

```
import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        JLabel label = new JLabel("labelMessage:");
        mainPanel.add(label);

        final JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea("textAreaMessage")
        {
//            @Override
//            public void setFont(Font f)
//            {
//                super.setFont(label.getFont());
//            }
        };
        textArea.setEditable(false);
        textArea.setOpaque(false);
        textArea.setFont(label.getFont());
        mainPanel.add(textArea);

        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Only, when uncommenting the override of `setFont` it works like one would expect.
When setting there a breakpoint one can see that when the font anti-aliasing is changed there is a AATextListener fired:
[image]

Where at some point the defaults are installed:
`editor.setFont(UIManager.getFont(prefix /*TextArea*/ + ".font"));`

So it is clear why it is happening but I do not know how to solve it in a good fashion.

Possible solutions:

1. Override the methods like shown above in the code
2. Use e.g. `-Dswing.useSystemFontSettings=false` (or `-Dswing.aatext=true` or `awt.useSystemAAFontSettings`) BUT then the font looks ugly so not acceptable without further enhancements
3. Set via UIManager the defaults
4. Remove/disable the listener? Seems to be hard coded and not be doable easy?
5. or 3. could be a solution but would require much work in a big legacy app.

NOTE: This is just a simple example. In our app the problem is much bigger as not only set fonts are lost, but almost everything, like borders of buttons, the custom ComponentUIs etc. And the described way how to reproduce it was just to have it easy reproducible, means we encounter this issue also spontaneously when e.g. the app runs for some hours. We then see that some windows event is firing the listener and destroying the look and feel of our app (often the PC was not used at all for almost an hour when this suddenly happens).

Maybe I will also ask the OpenJDK community the next days, as well. If so, I will link the ticket ID here.

Windows version: Windows Enterprise 10 Version 20H2 (Build 19042.1348)
Java version: zulu11.50.19-ca-jdk11.0.12-win_x64

Comment: You may be able to listen for the change, by [adding a listener](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Toolkit.html#addPropertyChangeListener(java.lang.String,java.beans.PropertyChangeListener)) for the `"awt.font.desktophints"` property, whose value is a RenderingHints Map.  See https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/doc-files/DesktopProperties.html.

Comment: Thank you, that seems to solve the issue! I update the question with a code sample.

Comment: @ConstantinButzke you could've left the original question as is and, instead of editing the question with the answer, you could've simply answer your own question. This is allowed in Stack Overflow. You can still do that if  you want. I suggest you do.

Comment: I’m not sure removing all existing desktop hint listeners is a good approach.  It may cause problems on other platforms and it may not work at all in other versions of Java.  It certainly is neither documented nor guaranteed.  I was thinking you could add your own listener, so you can monitor the changes and adjust your own components accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

It's an old question but I'd like to explain what's going on here.

```
textArea.setFont(label.getFont());
```

You use the font of the `label` for `textArea`. Since you didn't change the font, the font is a `UIResource`, therefore the font gets reset to the default font whenever UI components are updated because of a desktop property change or any other update, like Look-and-Feel change.

When such an event occurs, the UI of all the components is updated using [`updateUI()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JComponent.html#updateUI()) method of `JComponent`.

Creating a new instance of `Font` removes the magic of `UIResource`:

```
Font labelFont = label.getFont();
textArea.setFont(labelFont.deriveFont(labelFont.getStyle()));
```

The font of the `textArea` is not reset by `updateUI`. Yet the font will not change even when you want it to change, for example when the Look-and-Feel of your app is updated to another LaF.

A better solution is to override `updateUI` method and set the font for `textArea` there:

```
final JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea("textAreaMessage") {
    @Override
    public void updateUI() {
        super.updateUI();
        setFont(UIManager.getFont("Label.font"));
    }
};
```

This approach handles both the initial setup as well as any updates. This can be a new reusable component which is used to display selectable text, if you also set the background and foreground colors and make the text non-editable by default. (If you set the background and foreground colors, which I recommend doing, you won't need `textArea.setOpaque(false);`, it makes paint and repaint faster.)

The runnable example:

```java
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class UIFontUpdate {

    private final JFrame frame;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(UIFontUpdate::new);
    }

    private UIFontUpdate() {
        frame = new JFrame("UI Font Update");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        JLabel label = new JLabel("labelMessage:");
        mainPanel.add(label);

        final JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea("textAreaMessage") {
            @Override
            public void updateUI() {
                super.updateUI();
                setFont(UIManager.getFont("Label.font"));
            }
        };
        textArea.setEditable(false);
        textArea.setOpaque(false);
        mainPanel.add(textArea);

        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        new Thread(this::callUpdateUI).start();
    }

    public void callUpdateUI() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ignored) { }

        System.out.println("UI updating...");
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() ->
                SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(frame));
    }
}
```

I'm simulating update to properties without actually changing system settings. I'm using `callUpdateUI` which is run on another thread, and after 2 seconds it updates the UI.

To test that the approach works when changing the Look-and-Feel, change the code `callUpdateUI` to:

```java
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException
                    | IllegalAccessException
                    | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ignored) {
            }
            SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(frame);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Demo which listens for change like proposed by @VGR. When font anti aliasing is changed the UI will be re-rendered.

```
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
     
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            
            final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            final JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
            
            Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
            tk.addPropertyChangeListener("awt.font.desktophints"/*SunToolkit.DESKTOPFONTHINTS*/, new PropertyChangeListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt)
                {
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> render(mainPanel));
                }
            });

            render(mainPanel);
            
            frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    private static void render(JPanel parent)
    {
        parent.removeAll();
        final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        final JLabel label = new JLabel("labelMessage:");
        panel.add(label);
        
        final JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea("textAreaMessage");
        textArea.setEditable(false);
        textArea.setOpaque(false);
        textArea.setFont(label.getFont());
        panel.add(textArea);
        parent.add(panel);
        
        parent.revalidate();
        parent.repaint();
    }
}
```

Comment: This approach works but you re-creating components when the desktop property changes. If the message displayed in `textArea` could be updated dynamically, you would need to copy it to the newly created component. If the `textArea` was editable, you would need to copy the text; if it had any undo information saved, the undo info would become lost. And changes to other desktop properties can also lead to updating the UI.